# How do I properly add a reference from my Github project to someone elses in VS2013 on Windows 8?

Tags: git, github, source-code, reference

I need to reference the latest version of Bouncy Castle in a project I intend to publish to Github.

In my first posting of the code to Github, someone complained that I downloaded the entire Bouncy Castle library, added it as a project, and uploaded it.

What is the correct way to link to the latest version of this Bouncy Castle DLL so that my references are properly maintained?

Comment: [Git Submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) are an option, although that adds significant complexity of its own.

Comment: Are Bouncy Castle releases signed?  If not download the repository, build it, the copy the output to your project.  If you want a signed release you could in theory sign it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [Bouncy Castle has a NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle). You could set up your VS2013 solution for [package restore](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore), and then reference Bouncy Castle through [NuGet](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget).

By doing so, you don't actually store the referenced files in your repository at all, just the NuGet reference. Then, when somebody else builds your project, the package restore process will download the files from the (NuGet) source for them.

Comment: That build is from Saturday, April 30 2011, I need the one from Feb 2014

Comment: I see. I assumed you were looking for the latest released version, which is 1.7 from April 2011. You could always ask them to create a NuGet package for the latest beta version... NuGet is really the correct way to go to accomplish what you want.